# how to solve webview flutter overrides a deprecated API?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-build

[image]

app is running perfectly fine and webview no longer using this project then why its showing error?

```
ERROR
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.                
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.                    
Note: /Users/ali/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter- 
0.3.22+1/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/webviewflutter/FlutterWebView.java uses 
unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.                      
Note: /Users/ali/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/url_launcher- 
5.7.2/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/urllauncher/WebViewActivity.java uses or 
overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to:

add below code in `Android/app/build.gradle` file

```
configurations {
compile.exclude group: 'com.google.zxing'
}
```